# I want to use the GD image editor for just one function then switch back to ImageMagick

Tags: images

I have issues with ImageMagick generating images with transparency, they work but when I have wordpress resize them they come out a little distorted.

I asked a question about this many moons ago in more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230166/png-images-resized-via-wordpress-are-losing-some-shades-of-gray

The only solution I was able to find was to turn ImageMagick off and use GD when uploading and creating image sizes. I've ran into to a problem though, because I now need to use ImageMagick to generate pdf images.

I use Aqua Resizer to generate my normal images and thumbnail, if possible I would like temporarily use GD for this function, but keep ImageMagick as default for creating pdf images.

I know how to make GD default:

```
function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';

    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );

    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
```

Right now I'm using Aqua Resizer to create my image sizes and storing them in a cache folder. For this function I would like to use GD, but for anything else I would like to use ImageMagick.

Is this possible?